# Xdebug-SublimeText2 : No URL defined in project settings file

Tags: php, xdebug, sublimetext2

I've a problem using a plugin in SublimeText2. The name is "SublimeXdebug".

When I click on [shift]+[F8], there a error message :
 `No URL defined in project settings file`

So, I create a **.sublime-project** file in the root of the folder **/var/www/tests/** like this :

```
{
"folders":
    [
        {
            "path": "/var/www/tests"
        }
    ],

"settings": {
    "xdebug": { "url": "http://localhost/tests" }
}

}
```

The file that I test is : the /var/www/tests/mail.php

How can I do this ?

Thanx,

F.

Answer (score 1):

The `No URL defined in project settings file` can be safely ignored if you would like to manually enable/disable the debugging session on the web server or use a browser extension.

If you put the xdebug url in your `.sublime-project` file, it will just open your default browser to that address and append `?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=sublime.xdebug` whenever you start a debugging session.

I much prefer using a browser extension as you have much more control over starting and stopping the sessions. There are a number available, but here is a list from the XDebug website:

> ### easy Xdebug for FireFox
>
> This extension for Firefox was built to make
>   debugging with an IDE easier. You can find the extension at
>   https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/58688/.
>
> ### Xdebug Helper for Chrome
>
> This extension for Chrome will help you to enable/disable
>   debugging and profiling with a single click. You can find the
>   extension at https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc.
>
> ### Xdebug Toggler for Safari
>
> This extension for Safari allows you to auto
>   start Xdebug debugging from within Safari. You can get it from Github
>   at https://github.com/benmatselby/xdebug-toggler.
>
> ### Xdebug launcher for Opera
>
> This extension for Opera allows you to start an Xdebug session
>   from Opera.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for help.

I'll try the addon with Firefox, and tell you if it's works.

Have a good day.
Fabrice